# I cant get the property value in kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Im getting
cannot read property value

```
const valor = $('#PreguntaPA044').find('input[name^=Pre]').data("kendoDropDownList").value(); 

#PreguntaBody2665 > span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header

<span title="" style="width: 100%;" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-owns="Pre_2665_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="606f2dc7-64b7-4c15-863d-97fe636ddc6c">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Si</span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
</span>
</span>

<input id="Pre_2665" name="Pre_2665" required="" value="" style="width: 100%; display: none;" data-role="dropdownlist" class="k-valid"></span>
```

xpath

```
//*[@id="PreguntaBody2665"]/span[1]
```

I tried

```
const valor = $('Pre_2665').data("kendoDropDownList").value();
```

with the same error

UPDATE ***************************************************

tHE solution

```
const valor = $('#Pre_2665').data("kendoDropDownList").value(); 
                
if (valor == 9568) {                    
  $('#PreguntaPH047').find('input[name^=Pre]:input').attr('required', true);                    
  $('#PreguntaPH048').find('input[name^=Pre]:input').attr('enabled', true);                    
  $('#PreguntaPH049').find('input[name^=Pre]:input').attr('enabled', true);
} else  {                   
  $('#PreguntaPH050').find('input[name^=Pre]:input').attr('required', true);
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `.value();` with `.val();`... ;) [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/) - Have a look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) where you should have had `.value() is not a function` kind of error.

Comment: `.val()` is jquery method `.value()` is kendo method. Proper way to get value is like this: `$('#Pre_2665').data("kendoDropDownList").value();` But I agree, few fundamental things are wrong here. Start with documentation

Comment: Thanks to both, i have updated the question with the solution. I had to start on a project , with minimal knowledge of Jquery thats why I have this kind of errors, thanks for your patience. Im going to read the links you provided